# How to create custom events in Javascript? (compatible with IE8 and using Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, polyfills

I created a placeholder Polyfill and to simplify it, I'm using `value` to set the placeholder value. Of course the danger of this is that if you submit a form with placeholders it will submit the values.

To fix this, I added two new custom events : `onbeforesubmit` and `onaftersubmit`.

So far I can get this working but I have two questions:

1. How to modify's `submit` prototype to have the following behavior for all forms (right now I'm setting it after document load on all forms rather than using prototype which is quite anoying):

   ```
   element.onsubmit = function () {
           element.onbeforesubmit();
           element.submit();
           element.onaftersubmit();
           return false;
   }
   ```
2. Right now I modified `HTMLFormElement`'s prototype to include the two new events like this:

   ```
   HTMLFormElement.prototype.onbeforesubmit = function () {};
   HTMLFormElement.prototype.onaftersubmit = function () {};
   ```

   I'm pretty sure this is not the right way since I cannot use `addEventListener` with these two new properties. For now I'm resorting to use the following syntax which is again less than ideal. How can I make this work like normal events?

   ```
   element.form.onbeforesubmit = function () {
        element.value = '';
   }
   ```

   What I'm hoping to get to is simply (in that case using a `addEventListener` polyfill for IE8 but not other browsers):

   ```
   element.form.addEventListener('beforesubmit', function () {
        element.value = '';
   }
   ```

Comment: IE8 does not support `addEventListener`

Comment: @Oriol With a Polyfill yes.